# Users Can't See Community HomePage from Salesforce Mobile App Switcher; Missing home page functionality for communities in Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: community, lightning-apps, mobile, community-builder

I have followed the instructions here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_access_in_salesforce1.htm&type=5 for

Users with standard Salesforce licenses
Internal org users who are also in a community

"Log in to the app. Use the switcher at the top of the navigation menu and select a community."

But no user can see the community home page. It is not part of any tab, etc. The only workaround I could find online was to use JavaScript to redirect users like: window.open(url);

But it seems like the users are missing a lot of functionality that is probably a configuration I am missing somehow. Any advice? Shouldn't the user be able to access the community home page from this url switcher as a logged in internal user similar to the way they can on the desktop?

It's a regular community, not lightning communities.

Comment: They do not want to enter the server URL as instructed here: On the Salesforce app login screen, tap iOS Choose Connection icon. Add the community as a new connection, using the community URL for the host name: (<domainname>.force.com/​<path-prefix>).

Then, select the community connection and log in with the community credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer to this was to use a redirect with the EXACT correct link. I had to use the old links like /servlet/networks/switch?networkId=[yournetworkidhere] instead of trying to use the URL of the community itself for the redirect.